# Random disk I/O failures in a native Android app

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-ndk, filesystems

Some of our Android native tests, specifically the ones that do disk I/O started intermittently failing recently. I have traced it down to Java's `File.mkdirs()` failing to create the `/data/user/0/com.company.app/files` folder, but see no reason why this happens. Here are some of the observations:

- The issue happens seemingly randomly and independently of the build
- Affects multiple devices, for example Asus Zenfone 2, Galaxy S5 and S7; all devices are rooted
- There is enough storage space on the devices
- Certain log messages seem to correlate (but never 100%) with the failures, for example:

> D StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation; ~duration=329 ms:
>   android.os.StrictMode$StrictModeDiskReadViolation: policy=65567
>   violation=2 D StrictMode: at
>   android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onReadFromDisk(StrictMode.java:1263)
>   D StrictMode: at
>   android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.awaitLoadedLocked(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:203)
>   D StrictMode: at
>   android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:262)
>   D StrictMode: at
>   android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:482)
>   D StrictMode: at
>   android.preference.PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(PreferenceManager.java:445)
>   D StrictMode: at com.android.mms.MmsApp.onCreate(Unknown Source) D
>   StrictMode: at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1013)
>   D StrictMode: at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4767)
>   D StrictMode: at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java) D StrictMode:
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1421) D
>   StrictMode: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) D
>   StrictMode: at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) D StrictMode:
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5480) D
>   StrictMode: at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) D
>   StrictMode: at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>   D StrictMode: at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

or

> E UninstallPackageIntentO: Package still installed com.company.app

- We are re-installing the app before running the tests

Thanks!